# Open txt file and replace text in the first two lines (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am writing this program that allows me to generate txt files that with an incremental number, however, i want each file serial number to be writting inside the txt file itself.

For example:
I generated 3 files, Mytext-000001.txt, Mytext-000002.txt, Mytext-000003.txt, and each file first line contains "Hello 000000" and the second line contains "My number is 000000", now i want to change each txt file to contain "Hello " + the incremental number that it is named with.

**So the output of each file will be:**

```
Mytext-000001.txt,
Hello 000001
My number is 000001

Mytext-000002.txt,
Hello 000002
My number is 000002


Mytext-000003.txt,
Hello 000002
My number is 000003
```

**My Code**

```
string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + @"\path.txt";
string pth_input = null;
string pth_output = null;

using (StreamReader sx = File.OpenText(path))
{
    pth_input = sx.ReadLine();
    pth_output = sx.ReadLine();
}


Console.WriteLine("Number of Files?");
string number_of_files = Console.ReadLine();
int get_number_of_files = Int32.Parse(number_of_files) + 1;

string PathFiletoCopy = pth_input;
string Extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(PathFiletoCopy);
string PartialNewPathFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(PathFiletoCopy), System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(PathFiletoCopy) + "-");

for (int i = 1; i < get_number_of_files; i++)
{
    System.IO.File.Copy(PathFiletoCopy, PartialNewPathFile + i.ToString("D6") + Extension);
}
string[] txtfiles = Directory.GetFiles(pth_output, "*.txt");
foreach (var file in txtfiles)
{
    string get_file_counter = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(file.Substring(7,6));
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
    FileStream fi = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fi))
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            string line = null;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

             string replace_line_one = line.Replace("Hello 000001","Hello"+ "["+get_file_counter+"]");
             string replace_line_two = line.Replace("My number is 000001", "My number is" + "[" + get_file_counter + "]");

            }
            writer.Close();
        } reader.Close();

    } 
}
Console.Read();
```

I hope you can help

Appreciate your help guys

Comment: Looks like you already have some code trying to do that. What is the actual problem? You are to be commended for posting your code, but what is the problem?

Comment: Hey, the error that i am getting is that, cant access the file because it is being used by another process.

Comment: `FileReadAllLines()`; then replace as desired; `FileWriteAllLines()`

Comment: You have two `FileStream`s pointing at the same file. Of course you're getting access errors.

Comment: What line does it occur on? note: this all goes a lot faster when you explain the full story. Basically you should just use one Filestream in open mode. The one in read mode is redundant (and is locking your file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, "*.txt");
Regex regex = new Regex("\\d+(?=\\.txt)");

foreach (var file in files)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
    string number = regex.Match(Path.GetFileName(file)).Value;

    lines[0] = "Hello " + number;
    lines[1] = "My number is " + number;

    File.WriteAllLines(file, lines);
}
```

Regex makes this solution nonspecific.

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you

```
System.IO.Directory myDir = pth_output;
int count = (myDir.GetFiles().Length) + 1;
string thenumber = String.Format("0:000000", count);
string filename = "Mytext-" + thenumber + ".txt";
string filetext = "Hello " + thenumber + Environment.NewLine + "My number is " + thenumber;
File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(myDir,filename) , createText);
```

In `myDir` I am expecting you can pull the path of the folder which contains all the txt files.

`myDir.GetFiles().Length` will give you the count of the files exists in the folder and as we want only txt files you can search it like `Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;` instead

`String.Format("0:000000", count);` will give you the number in your format of preceding zeros.

Comment: Happy to help @user1848210. Another way of saying thanks would be you can upvote the answer.